# Dropping a Component In Codename One to The Last Position

Tags: java, codenameone

I have enabled drag and drop in my [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) `Container` and and placed draggable components within. I did this using:

```
container.setDropTarget(true);
```

And for the components I used `setDraggable(true)`

This works seamlessly for the most part when I drop above another child container. If I dropped below all the child components within the parent `Container` the drop operation fails. I want the child container to be positioned last if they are dropped in that black area which is the area of parent container.

[image]

Migrated from [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/codenameone-discussions/QMVTT9109ck/4WyR_Yq-FgAJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the `Container` stretches to that position and that the black area is indeed a part of that `Container` and not a part of the parent.

Assuming that is the case, override the `drop` method in your `Container` and make sure its invoked correctly for that situation. Assuming that it is, you can detect the position via the y argument and add the component to the right location.

```
public void drop(Component dragged, int x, int y) {
    int i = getComponentIndex(dragged);
    if(i > -1) {
        Component dest = getComponentAt(x, y);
        if(dest != dragged) {
            int destIndex = getComponentIndex(dest);
            if(destIndex > -1 && destIndex != i) {
                removeComponent(dragged);
                Object con = getLayout().getComponentConstraint(dragged);
                if(con != null) {
                    addComponent(destIndex, con, dragged);
                } else {
                    addComponent(destIndex, dragged);
                }
            }
        }
        animateLayout(400);
    } else {
        Container oldParent = dragged.getParent();
        if(oldParent != null) {
            oldParent.removeComponent(dragged);
        }
        Component pos = getComponentAt(x, y);
        i = getComponentIndex(pos);
        if(i > -1) {
            addComponent(i, dragged);
        } else {
            addComponent(dragged);
        }
        getComponentForm().animateHierarchy(400);
    }
}
```